# Text appear all caps in Action Bar Tabs in Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Hello I am using the `Sherlock` library to achieve the `ActionBarTabs` in Android but there is some weird issue that text appear in the `Tabs` are all caps. I dont want to make all caps to captital. How can I achive this ?

I tried this but this is not working

values-v14.xml

```
<style name="TariffPlansTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="TariffPlansActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_tariff_plans"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:theme="@style/TariffPlansTheme">
</activity>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved my issue. I was using wrong parent style `Menu` instead of `Tab`

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />

    <style name="TariffPlansTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/My.TabText.Style</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/My.TabText.Style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My.TabText.Style" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```