# How to change tab background color in action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-tabs

i am implementing tabs with action bar 
but i am fail in change background color of tabs 
can one help me.

Thanks in advance.

**My output**

[image]

**My Required output**

[image]

for that bottom stript red color i am using below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_example" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

</selector>
```

**Change capital to small**
[Text appear all caps in Action Bar Tabs in Sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198790/text-appear-all-caps-in-action-bar-tabs-in-sherlock)

```
<style name="My.TabText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

**Change action color and tabs color**

```
// set background for action bar
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0c2354")));

// set background for action bar tab
bar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#B5C0D0")));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ActionBar Tab Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585002/android-actionbar-tab-color)

Comment: ActionBar tabs are deprecated

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jared Burrows, If ActionBar tabs are deprecated can i know what is the latest one...

Comment: Answer: // set background for action bar actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DC180C"))); // set background for action bar tab actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_select)));

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
                 for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01afeb")); // unselected
                    TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
                    //Unselected Tabs
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                }

                mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f9b526")); // selected
                TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab

                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#01afeb"));
```

Comment: By Default tabs text coming in capital letters how i have to change that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you change the theme of the application to Holo Light for example like this

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" ... />
```

More information could be found here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Or without changing the whole theme like this for example:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("FFAB00"));
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriella Angelova,....Edited my required output screen if you observed that actionbar having red color and tabs having gray color with red color bottom stript(selected tab identification), if i apply setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("FFAB00")); i am not getting my required o/p

Comment: // set background for action bar
  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DC180C")));

  // set background for action bar tab
  actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_select)));

Comment: By Default tabs text coming in capital letters how i have to change that

Comment: you could create a new theme and set them not to be capitalized. See this question for more  information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953240/tab-widget-have-always-in-capital-alphabets-in-android-4-0